# MongoDB: querying fields of a referenced document

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm writing a Flask app that reports on different metrics relating to content items (e.g. number of views). The metrics data is imported from various sources, and I'm using MongoDB to store it locally. I'm querying it using MongoEngine in Flask.

The data structure is as follows:

Each 'MetricData' document references a 'Metric' and a 'ContentInstance' (i.e. one Metric has many MetricData, and one ContentInstance has many MetricData) - here's an example of a 'metric_data' document in the mongo shell:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536b05fc182aff24ca916c22"),
    "metric" : ObjectId("536ae244182aff1f222f00c7"),
    "content_instance" : ObjectId("536adcef182aff1e73d6e021"),
    ...
}
```

And each 'ContentInstance' document references a 'Category' and a 'Source' (i.e. one Category has many ContentInstance, and one Source has many ContentInstance) - here's an example of a 'content_instance' document in the mongo shell:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536adcef182aff1e73d6e043"),
    "category" : ObjectId("5369c352182aff28cf18e912"),
    "source" : ObjectId("5369c384182aff28cf18e914"),
    ...
}
```

I need to query the metrics data by metric, source, and category. I understand that I can't do joins, and that multiple queries are necessary. I just want to confirm that the queries I'm using are appropriate to this use case, and that there isn't another, more efficient, more scalable way of doing the same thing (that isn't much more complex).

If I were using a regular RDBMS with a regular Python ORM (such as Django's), I could just do this (but it doesn't work with MongoDB / MongoEngine):

```python
md_list = MetricData.objects.filter(metric__title__in=(
                                        'Number of views', 'Awesomeness'),
                                    content_instance__source__title__in=(
                                        'Google', 'Facebook'),
                                    content_instance__category__title__in=(
                                        'Apples', 'Oranges'))
```

Here's what I'm doing now, with MongoEngine (note: filtering by title is just an example, the actual filtering is based on a user's query):

```python
metric_list = Metric.objects.filter(title__in=('Number of views', 'Awesomeness'))
source_list = Source.objects.filter(title__in=('Google', 'Facebook'))
cat_list = Category.objects.filter(title__in=('Apples', 'Oranges'))
cont_inst_list = ContentInstance.objects.filter(source__in=source_list,
                                                category__in=cat_list)
md_list = MetricData.objects.filter(metric__in=metric_list,
                                    content_instance__in=cont_inst_list)
```

Is it OK to query like this? In particular, I'm worried about how many ContentInstance documents I'm returning from one query and passing as parameters to another - with my limited test data so far, the length of `cont_inst_list` is already 147. Any advice regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With EmbeddedDocumentField and EmbeddedDocument you can do a query like to Django ORM.

Example [Filtering an embedded list in MongoEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368695/filtering-an-embedded-list-in-mongoengine)

Comment: Good to know... however I'm not using EmbeddedDocument, just different Document models with reference fields. I need to query the metric data according to many different dimensions, the data doesn't "fit" nicely embedded within one particular collection... so EmbeddedDocument is not an option for me. I'm asking whether what I'm doing is the right approach, given that they're different top-level collections with references.